# what is diffrence bettween masking a char with 0xFF and casting (unsigned char)

Tags: c, casting, char, unsigned, bit-masks

```
    unsigned char Mid;

if( (data[2]) == 0x9A){
    Mid = data[5];

    if( (Mid == 1) || (Mid == 2) || (Mid == 3) )
        return(Mid);
```

The code above gives:

> warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type

error as I expected.

It's ok if I type

```
if( (unsigned char)data[2] == 0x9A){
```

or

```
if( (data[2]&0xFF) == 0x9A){
```

I understand the first one, but what happens in the second one?

What is the effect of masking with `0xFF`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- When casting the value to unsigned char, you are doing an explicit type conversion.
- When you mask the value with `0xFF`, an *implicit type conversion* takes place.

You have the signed char `data[2]` and `0xFF` as operands to the bitwise AND operator. Because one of the operands (`0xFF`) cannot fit inside a signed char, both operands are implicitly converted into an unsigned type.